# Cannot use awk in alias command chain

Tags: bash, awk, alias

I'd like to add this command chain to alias to have a shorthand:

```
tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

However, as alias it does not work as it should:

```
alias ttn="tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10"
```

I tried to use single quote instead of double quote or use an escape character `\` before awk's quotes but none worked. So appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure you need `awk` anyway and not just `cut -d' ' -f1`? It depends what the first white space is in your input file - if every line starts with non-white-space followed by a blank char then you can just use `cut` instead of `awk` (which would be slower).

Comment: backslashing only `$` does not work but this one is fine: `alias ttn='tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '\''{print $1}'\'' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10'` . Please answer and I'll accept.

Comment: This is one reason why functions are better than aliases: you can avoid quoting hell. `ttn() { tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10"; }`

Comment: @glennjackman as an answer, please :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

This is one reason why functions are better than aliases: you can avoid quoting hell.

```bsh
ttn() { tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10; }
```

or, more readably

```bsh
ttn() { 
    tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log | 
      awk '{print $1}' | 
      sort | 
      uniq -c | 
      sort -nr | 
      head -10
}
```

or, another multi-line style:

```bsh
ttn() { 
    tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -nr \
    | head -10
}
```

Comment: I call this `ttn()` an elegant solution! Did not know I can use functions as alias. Thanks!